# Filter for DC component in FFT2 of image

Tags: image, matlab, filter, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to get the main frequency of the Fourier Transform of the image below, which is the intereference pattern detected by a CMOS sensor.
[image]

When I apply fft2, I got the DC peak at 0 frequency, that I know it can be suppressed if I do `FT = fft2(image-mean2(image))`. However, I only obtain a 0 in the `(1,1)` position, but the "neighbor" frequencies in the first row and column have still a higher magnitude that the peak I want to detect, which is in the `(6,11)` position.
[image]

Is there a formal way to filter the image, meaning without imposing `FT(1,:) = 0, FT(:,1) = 0`, in order to be able to extract directly that peak?

Comment: Maybe, `FT(FT == max(FT,[],'all','linear')) = 0` to remove the dominant frequency/spectral component.

Comment: Check [this amazing post on the subject](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/73769/55891), there is another [very detailed answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/73631/55891) (the same guy) to a related question.

Comment: The low-frequency components are certainly valid, since your image is concentrated into the lower-left corner.  Maybe you just want to ignore them.